# Browser not loading Php pages

Tags: php, mysql, apache, browser

Im using a linux machine, and I followed the instructions seen on https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php to setup php, apache and my sql.

I did exactly what it said and nothing more, but when I try to open a .php file with firefox or chrome, it downloads...?

Im following a tutorial on learning php seen here: http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/625

Comment: What url are you trying to use in Firefox/Chrome?
Just want to make sure you aren't trying to serve the file through Firefox rather than through Apache.

Comment: /home/USERNAME/WORK/PHP/Test_Page.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you have a `file://` URL in the browser address bar it isn't interacting with the server to process the page.

You will need to use `http://localhost/path/to/page/page.php`

Comment: So all im doing is replacing the 'file' with 'http'?

Thanks for the response

Comment: `file://` forces you browser to act as a very dumb version of the regular file manager on your OS. It will not cause the script to be run by the webserver, as the webserver never gets involved. Switching to `http://` will send a request to the webserver, which will load the script on your behalf.

Comment: Well I just did the replacement. and it redirected me to 'www.home.com' ?

Comment: then your apache is not listening (not running?) on port 80, so the browser tries to find a website which "sounds similar"..

Comment: You need to know where Apache is set to point to by default. Load `http://localhost` in your browser and see what happens.

Comment: It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Thats exactly what pops up...What does that mean?

Comment: Means that the server is running but you need to put your PHP scripts in that directory.

Comment: Well it seems like the default directory is '/var/www'

Thats where I found the html file, but when I saved my php file there...The same thing happened.

Comment: Define "nothing happened" better please. You saved the php file to `/var/www` and then loaded `http://localhost/[filename].php` into your web browser and nothing happened? No errors? Nothing?

Comment: Same thing happened = Was still downloading the php file.

Bt for whatever reason, what you typed works. :S

Do I have to type 'http://localhost/filname.php' EVERYTIME I want to test the php file?

Is there no other way that I can go about testing my .php files ?

Comment: Yeah, rename the file `index.php` and you can just type in `http://localhost/`. Also, you don't have to retype it everytime, just refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

According to this howto:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache.php

Please make sure you did steps 14 and 15,
what is happening - probably your webserver doesn't recognize php scripts AS php scripts, and sends those to your browser - resulting in either download or displaying the source.

Thanks

Comment: I have Apache 2.x on my machine. But I will attempt your suggestion, thanks for response

Comment: I ran the code 'LoadModule php5_module libexec/libphp5.so' in the terminal, it says 'command not found'.

So I didnt bother to go to number 15

Comment: LoadModule is not a command, you need to put it into apache's config.
For v2.0: Steps 7 and8 from this howto:
http://jm2.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php